# Car seat re-foaming

Tags: car, seat, campervan

I'm looking to re-foam our driver and passenger seats as the foam internal to the seat is a bit old and can feel the frame coming through, making the drive a bit uncomfortable on long journeys.

The car/van is a Toyota liteace noah 1998 2.0l petrol which we are converting to a campervan and looking at new/used seats are getting pricey.

I'm not a car nut or anything but am quite diy so don't mind getting my hands in there to strip and replace the foam and possibly the cover as well.

I have tried to search online but coming stuck.

I'm based in the Northamptonshire U.K.

I would like some advice on what the best way would be to remove the covers without damaging the covers to much and what would be the best way to get new foam.

Can you get generic seat foam or would I have to buy a block / multiple pieces and build it again? if so what would be the best but most cost effective foam to use, or should I just try and find someone due to it being cheaper that way?

If someone could recommend a website or where to start looking with a search.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: What is it your asking? Are you looking for how to do the repair or where to buy the materials? Information about where to buy the materials would be off-topic for this stack exchange..

Comment: Mainly what to search for to find the right foam or kind of foam to use and or any recommendations where to start looking as I don't know if I could use normal sofa foam or if there are places that would sell preformed foam for car seats

Comment: Google Northamptonshire auto upholstery. They should be able to get you what you need

Comment: As the OP is asking about REPAIRING his seats and wanting to source material - an offtopic classification is curious - he has not asked for prices...

Comment: @Mobius thanks I was using the wrong terminology so I'll look into that a bit later

Comment: @SolarMike thanks I didn't really know who to run to and I know the people on these forums (all of them) have been really helpful in the past with varying questions

Comment: @AdamMannPro : Oh yes, some are, but like the animals in George Orwell...

Comment: The junkyard is full of good used seats for very little money. I'd start there and look for an entire matching seat. Failing that, I'd find one with some thick foam that could be repurposed.

Comment: @cory in my area we dont have "junk" yard as such they are called breakers but can only buy from them but they jack the pricing up for parts.

Answer (score 1):

Best place to get foam would probably be a furniture place that does refurbishment - and the foam should be fire resistant etc. Then you need to shape it, but you have the old ones to provide a pattern. Take care removing the covers...

Edit update : Just a thought here, I just trod on my daughter's gym mat (1m wide 2m long) and it is a high density foam - that may be an alternative... As for pre-formed foam you would need to find the suppliers to the seat manufacturers... Then, will they sellto you or just direct to the manufacturer - contract or licensing issue possibly.

Comment: I thought about something like this. I haven't taken the seats apart just yet as I have to drive the car this next week so once I have done I can see how bad the underlying foam is so this might be an option